# Can not parse query in deno

Tags: javascript, deno

I started learning deno few days ago and i'm trying to parse query.

```
export const getBookQuery = async ({ request, response }) => {
  let kw = request.url.searchParams.get('keyword');
  // ...
};
```

It works that way but, i need to parse whole query and don't want to get values one by one.

P.S i use oak

Comment: There's multiple methods, such as [`entries`](https://deno.land/typedoc/classes/urlsearchparams.urlsearchparams-1.html#getall)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Object.fromEntries`

```
const query = Object.fromEntries(request.url.searchParams);
console.log(query);
console.log(query.keyword);
```